# Surjective *-homs between multiplier algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let A and B be C*-algebras, and let $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ be a *surjective* *-homomorphism.  Then $\phi$ is non-degenerate, and so we can extend it to *-homomorphism between the multiplier algebras: $\tilde\phi: M(A)\rightarrow M(B)$.  It's rather tempting to believe that then, surely, $\tilde\phi$ is also surjective.  But I cannot for the life of me think of a proof.  Any ideas...?

**Background:** The multiplier algebra $M(A)$ is the largest C*-algebra containing A as an essential ideal.  Concretely, pick some "large enough" representation of A (either $A\rightarrow B(H)$ a non-degenerate *-representation, or $A\rightarrow A^{**}$ say) and then $M(A) = \{ x : xa,ax\in A \ (a\in A)\}$ the idealiser of $A$ in our large ambient algebra.  As $\phi$ surjects, it's very easy to define $\tilde\phi$: we simply have that $$\tilde\phi(x) \phi(a) = \phi(xa), \quad \phi(a) \tilde\phi(x) = \phi(ax).$$
This is well-defined, for if $\phi(a)=0$, then given an approximate identity $(e_i)$ for A, we have that $\phi(xa) = \lim_i \phi(xe_i a) = \lim_i \phi(xe_i) \phi(a) = 0$, and so forth.  Indeed, if $B\subseteq B(K)$ say, then $\tilde\phi(x)$ is the limit (strong operator topology say) of the net $\phi(xe_i)$ in $B(K)$; then clearly this is in the idealiser of $B$, and so does define a member of $M(B)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true if $A$ is $\sigma$-unital, and is sometimes called the "noncommutative Tietze extension theorem".  A good reference is Proposition 6.8 in Lance's *Hilbert $C^*$-modules*.  Proposition 3.12.10 in Pedersen's *$C^*$-algebras and their automorphism groups* covers the separable case, which was first proved by Akemann, Pedersen, and Tomiyama in a 1973 paper called "[Multipliers of C*-algebras](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WJJ-4CRHY72-43&_user=440026&_coverDate=07%252F31%252F1973&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1394971669&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000020939&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=440026&md5=9ed3e6657608f669d2437593c461f3f6)".

Pedersen points out in Section 3.12.11 that you can get counterexamples in the commutative case by considering non-normal locally compact Hausdorff spaces, so that Tietze's extension theorem doesn't apply.

---

Akemann, Pedersen, and Tomiyama are more explicit:

> In fact let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff
>   space which is not normal, and consider two disjoint closed sets $Y_1$
>   and $Y_2$ such that the function $b$ which is one on $Y_1$ and zero on $Y_2$ has
>   no continuous extension to $X$. The restriction map of $C_0(X)$ to
>   $C_0(Y_2\cup Y_2)$ is surjective, and $b\in M(C_0(Y_1\cup Y_2))$, but $b$ is not the
>   image of a multiplier of $C_0(X)$.

Comment: Nice work, Jonas. In the commutative case, do you know if $\sigma$-unitality is necessary? That is, if $A=C)0(X)$ where $X$ is locally compact but not $\sigma$-compact, does there exist a quotient HM from $A$ onto some $B$ such that the induced map of multiplier algebras is not onto?

Comment: (grr, typo, but hopefully you know what I mean)

Comment: One of the few books I have at home is Lance's book... Must read more carefully in future!  Many thanks...

Comment: Yemon: My immediate answer is no, I do not know.  Matthew: You're welcome.

Comment: Yemon: It is not necessary, because there are normal locally compact Hausdorff spaces that are not $\sigma$-compact, like the discrete topology on an uncountable set. According to the reference table in the back of *Counterexamples in topology*, examples 42,45, and 109 also give examples of this.

Comment: Yemon: Moreover, Henno Brandsma points out a general method of constructing such examples, after I asked about it on Ask A Topologist: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist;task=show_msg;msg=0841.0001.0001

Comment: You're welcome.  Taking Henno's tip to C* land, I think the following works (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong):  If $\{A_i\}$ is a family of C*-algebras such that for each $i$, every surjective $*$-hom on $A_i$ extends to a surjective $*$-hom of the multiplier algebras, then the $c_0$ direct product of the $A_i$'s will also have this property, but if it is an uncountable family then this direct product will not be $\sigma$-unital.

Comment: I guess what I was getting at is that the result you refer to shows that $\sigma$-unitality suffices for this kind of NC-Tietze theorem, so I was just naively enquiring how far from being sharp this is.

Comment: Yes, that is how I understood your natural question, which I had myself but offhand didn't know how to answer, due to my insufficient general topology knowledge.  The question thus led to a slight but appreciated increase in that knowledge, and to at least some classes of examples showing the lack of sharpness.  The question of whether any interesting classification of algebras for which this holds in the NC case exists (NC-normal?) remains unanswered here.

Comment: This is all very interested: my original motivation was looking at locally compact groups, which are all normal (even if they can get very large).  I already knew the answer thanks to working at the level of continuous maps, but was worried that it didn't all follow from some C*-algebra generality.  Now I see that, indeed, you do have to do some special for groups.  So... I wonder if the same is true for C^*(G)??  I might make this a new question if I don't get anywhere with it...

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article is available at [doi:10.1016/0022-1236(73)90036-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(73)90036-0) ([Zbl 0258.46052](https://zbmath.org/0258.46052)).